# What intellisense settings I can use to change this behavior in Unity + Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

### This is a strange question so I will show a series of three gifs.

**This is what happens in visual studio code if i'm writing c# (as expected):**

https://gyazo.com/818c27f60d52b437dc3a7960d1e31b83

**This is what happens in visual studio if i'm writing c# (as expected):**

https://gyazo.com/80a5e28249fabc48192a6e051e157dbe

**This is how my visual studio will behave forever until i reset to default settings for c# if i ever open a unity project in it (wtf):**

https://gyazo.com/0eeb11d76fe6aab7343812882bd45314

Is this some problem specific to my env? Does unity have some default intellisense settings it's importing into my visual studio?

I tried the most recent 2 versions of unity and the most recent 2 versions of visual studio and get the same behavior.

It's extremely annoying because i have to reset my VS settings every time i open a unity project, if anyone knows what setting i am getting messed up i would be extremely grateful for an assist.

Comment: do you open the script from within Unity?

Comment: maybe also check `Tools` -> `Options` -> `Text Editor` -> `C#` -> `IntelliSense` -> `Enter key behaviour`

Comment: @derHugo actually if i open one script at a time from in the Unity editor, it works normally, but if i open the whole unity project in visual studio is when it gets messed up

Comment: You mean you open the `.sln` directly? Anyway it is a strange behaviour but opening a script from within Unity actually also loads the entire solution so there should not be that big difference..

Comment: @derHugo yeah, I have started opening the scripts from the Unity editor because it is fine that way. Thanks!

Comment: @derHugo And as to your question i was previously opening the unity project directory in visual studio.